# mmap /dev/mem, read performance is very slow

Tags: performance, mmap

I have written a test program which is like this:

```
fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR);
src = mmap(0x0, 0x1000000, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x80000000);/* 0x80000000 is     physical start address of DDR on my A8-cortex platform */
dst = malloc(0x1000000);
start_time = get_time()
memcpy(dst, src, 0x1000000);
end_time = get_time();
print_speed();
```

On my ARM A8-cortex based board, it gives me about 400MB/s. Then I changed the above test program, src buffer is also alllocated by malloc, test again, now it gives me about 1400MB/s, about 3~4X faster.

I try to figure out the reason. First, I suspect that the src memory is uncached through mmap, so I check out the code in driver/cha/mem.c in kernel. In mmap_mem function, I use printk to print the page attribute of maped address, vma->vm_pgoff shows 0x10f, so it is not uncached.
Further more, I change the code and set it uncached type through vma->vm_pgoff = pgprot_nocached(vma->vm_pgoff) and test again, the result is about 30MB/s. So, we can defenitly confirm that /dev/mem maped memory is surely cached, but its read performance is very slow as compared to malloced memory.

Then how to explain this test result?

Comment: It seems OP has posted somewhere and got an answer: http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/dev-mem-access-terribly-slow-Zynq/td-p/412277/page/2

Comment: update xilinx link. https://support.xilinx.com/s/feed/0D52E00006hpTATSA2?language=en_US